# Updating .htaccess to redirect to "www"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a website which uses a PHP framework (CodeIgniter) and I'm trying to redirect all the queries sent to **"mydomain.com"** to **www.mydomain.com"**. I made changes to the .htaccess, which now looks as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # I just added this part
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  # The default rule of the framework
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the problem is that it works fine when I enter **"mydomain.com"**, the user is redirected properly, but they are also redirected to this home page when they enter a more complex address like **"mydomain.com/Settings"**.

How can I address this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the redirect happening on the first hop or is it two redirects? You can use something like http://redirectcheck.com or the network tab in your browser to see the redirects being done. The reason I'm asking this is because your rule looks perfectly fine and it may be a second redirect after the fact coming from the framework.

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess/blob/master/README.md#force-www-in-a-generic-way).

Comment: have you change base_url() to www.mydomain.com in config.php file.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (example.com)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # I just added this part
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # The default rule of the framework
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

For me, the "framework" part of this can vary from server to server, and in my own experience I have these options:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# NORMAL SERVER ( COMMENT OUT IF GODADDY OR OPTION #3 )
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

# SPECIAL GODADDY LINE ( UNCOMMENT IF GODADDY )
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# IF NOTHING ELSE WORKS UNCOMMENT THIS ONE
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I know you were not asking about the "framework" part, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: No luck. I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```